# Internal server error when set cookie in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies, setcookie

In URL can additional parameters for example like utm_campaign

In view I get this parameters:

```
utm_campaign = request.GET.get('utm_campaign',None)
```

But when i wanna set this information in cookie I get *Internal Server Error* without traceback or another information

I was trying several solution:

```
response.set_cookie('utm_campaign',utm_campaign )
response.set_cookie('utm_campaign',utm_campaign .encode('utf-8'))
response.set_cookie('utm_campaign',utm_campaign .encode())
response.set_cookie('utm_campaign',request.GET.get('utm_campaign '))
```

What is the problem?

The problem is that if I write English text or numbers - everything works.
If I try write cyrillic text - there is an error without details.

- Python3
- CentOs7 (default "utf-8")
- Django 1.11 (default "utf-8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
from urllib import parse
response.set_cookie('utm_campaign', parse.quote(utm_campaign))
```